# Validator not added to chain when using array syntax

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In my Zend Framework 2 Form class, I add my element like so:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'passwordConfirm',
        'type' => 'Password',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required',
            'placeholder' => 'Confirm password',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Confirm password',
            'column-size' => 'sm-10',
            'label_attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'col-sm-2',
            ),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'NotEmpty',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Identical',
                'options' => array(
                    'token' => 'password',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Which is just as described in the [official reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#form-elements). I create an new instance of the form like so:

```
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('user.auth.form');
    $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($this->entityManager());
    $form->setHydrator($hydrator);
    $form->bind($user);
```

However, the `validators` are not being added to the elements validator chain. Here is the output of `var_dump($form->get('passwordConfirm'));`

```
object(Zend\InputFilter\Input)[506]
  protected 'allowEmpty' => boolean true
  protected 'continueIfEmpty' => boolean false
  protected 'breakOnFailure' => boolean false
  protected 'errorMessage' => null
  protected 'filterChain' => 
    object(Zend\Filter\FilterChain)[507]
       protected 'plugins' => null
       protected 'filters' => 
        object(Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue)[508]
          protected 'queueClass' => string 'Zend\Stdlib\SplPriorityQueue' (length=28)
          protected 'items' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'queue' => null
      protected 'options' => 
         array (size=0)
           empty
   protected 'name' => string 'passwordConfirm' (length=15)
   protected 'notEmptyValidator' => boolean false
   protected 'required' => boolean false
   protected 'validatorChain' => 
     object(Zend\Validator\ValidatorChain)[509]
      protected 'plugins' => null
      protected 'validators' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'messages' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  protected 'value' => null
  protected 'fallbackValue' => null
  protected 'hasFallback' => boolean false
```

And when I input invalid input for the validator, the form is accepted by `$form->isValid()` without a problem.

What'd I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the source and trying some other things with this syntax I found out that you simply cannot add a validator using this array syntax as of Zend Framework 2.3. The example from the official documentation I quote above is just plain wrong.

For validation, use the more elaborate syntax described in the part on `Zend\Validator` in the reference.